# No ip address allocated to my newly created ubuntu vm on Hyper-V

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, hyper-v

I just created a new Ubuntu vm using Window's Hyper-V Manager.

Inside the Ubuntu VM if I do `hostname -i` I expected a different ip-address. 
However, currently the command returns me `127.0.1.1` which means localhost. Can someone explain to me why this is the case? Can local vms not be allocated static dedicated ip-addresses? If yes then how do to do?

Comment: What are you using to issue DHCP? Are you using a bridge from local <-> VM and as such, being natted behind your host IP?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. My virtual switch in Hyper-V is set to Default Switch. I do not understand what it means.